# Error reading field 'topic_metadata': Error reading array of size 873589, only 41 bytes available

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, logstash, apache-zookeeper, logstash-configuration

I have installed **logstash** version 5.2.2 by downloading zip file in a VM having fresh **Ubuntu** installed in it.

I have created a sample config file **logstash-sample.conf** with the following entry

```
input{
        stdin{ }
}
output{
        stdout{ }
}
```

And executing the command **$bin/logstash -f logstash-simple.conf**
it is running absolutely fine.

Now in the same Ubuntu machine, I installed **kafka** by following the exact same process mentioned
here https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-kafka-on-ubuntu-14-04 and followed till step no 7.

Then I modified the **logstash-sample.conf** file to contain the following

```
input {
        kafka{
                bootstrap_servers => "localhost:9092"
                topics => ["TutorialTopic"]
        }
}
output {
        stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

And this time I am getting the following **error**,

sample@sample-VirtualBox:~/Downloads/logstash-5.2.2$ bin/logstash -f logstash-sample.conf

```
Sending Logstash's logs to /home/rs-switch/Downloads/logstash-5.2.2/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties
[2017-03-07T00:26:25,629][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Starting pipeline {"id"=>"main", "pipeline.workers"=>1, "pipeline.batch.size"=>125, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>5, "pipeline.max_inflight"=>125}
[2017-03-07T00:26:25,650][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Pipeline main started
[2017-03-07T00:26:26,039][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Exception in thread "Ruby-0-Thread-14: /home/rs-switch/Downloads/logstash-5.2.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-input-kafka-5.1.6/lib/logstash/inputs/kafka.rb:229" org.apache.kafka.common.protocol.types.SchemaException: Error reading field 'topic_metadata': Error reading array of size 873589, only 41 bytes available
        at org.apache.kafka.common.protocol.types.Schema.read(org/apache/kafka/common/protocol/types/Schema.java:73)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.parseResponse(org/apache/kafka/clients/NetworkClient.java:380)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.handleCompletedReceives(org/apache/kafka/clients/NetworkClient.java:449)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(org/apache/kafka/clients/NetworkClient.java:269)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.clientPoll(org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/internals/ConsumerNetworkClient.java:360)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/internals/ConsumerNetworkClient.java:224)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/internals/ConsumerNetworkClient.java:192)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/internals/ConsumerNetworkClient.java:163)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureCoordinatorReady(org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/internals/AbstractCoordinator.java:179)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollOnce(org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.java:974)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.java:938)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java/lang/reflect/Method.java:498)
        at RUBY.thread_runner(/home/rs-switch/Downloads/logstash-5.2.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-input-kafka-5.1.6/lib/logstash/inputs/kafka.rb:239)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(java/lang/Thread.java:745)
[2017-03-07T00:26:28,742][WARN ][logstash.agent           ] stopping pipeline {:id=>"main"}
```

Can anyone help me out resolving this issue? I am really stuck setting up ELK from last few weeks, but was not successful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You most probably have a version conflict that is causing this issue. Check out the [compatibility matrix](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-kafka.html#_description_16) in the Logstash Kafka input plugins documentation.

The link you mentioned for installing Kafka has you install version 0.8.2.1 which will not work with Kafka 0.10 clients. Kafka has version checking and backwards compatibility, but only if the broker is newer than the client, which is not the case here.
I'd recommend installing a current version of Kafka, there have been immense improvements since version 0.8 that you'd be missing out on if you tried downgrading Logstash instead.

Check out the [Confluent Platform Quickstart](http://docs.confluent.io/3.2.0/quickstart.html) for an easy way to get started.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks @Sönke Liebau .. It was indeed a version mismatch issue. I used Logstash 5.2.2 and Kafka 10.2.0 using the following mirror http://mirror.cc.columbia.edu/pub/software/apache/kafka/0.10.2.0/kafka_2.12-0.10.2.0.tgz  and it worked.